# hard code SLACK_API_TOKEN into javascript code

Tags: javascript, slack-api

using https://www.npmjs.com/package/slack-client

expects you to make an extra file just for the token and to get it you must do

```
process.env.SLACK_API_TOKEN
```

I don't like this approach of creating a file just for the sake of a token!

My code is server side, already in a directory that users cannot see so I would like to just write the token into the javascript as an object/string/array

I have so far failed with array

```
var token=[
    'SLACK_TOKEN=xxxx'
,   'SLACK_CLIENT_ID=xxxx'
,   'SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxx'
    ];
```

and string

```
var token=
    'SLACK_TOKEN=xxxx\n'
+   'SLACK_CLIENT_ID=xxxx\n'
+   'SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxx'
    ;
```

and object

```
var token={
    SLACK_TOKEN:'xxxx'
,   SLACK_CLIENT_ID:'xxxx'
,   SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET:'xxxx'
    };
```

Everyone else's apis just get you to put things like secret keys inside srings or objects like normal! How can I do this the normal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.env.SLACK_API_TOKEN` isn't a file, it's an environment variable. The advantage of keeping your API key there is that you can't accidentally commit it to version control. That said, the page you linked to makes it pretty clear that you don't have to use it:

```
var RtmClient = require('slack-client').RtmClient;

var token = process.env.SLACK_API_TOKEN || '';

var rtm = new RtmClient(token, {logLevel: 'debug'});
rtm.start();
```

Just set the `token` variable to your API token, then pass it as the first parameter to `new RtmClient()`:

```
var RtmClient = require('slack-client').RtmClient;

var token = 'YOUR SLACK API TOKEN';

var rtm = new RtmClient(token, {logLevel: 'debug'});
rtm.start();
```

Comment: your code gives me `[Error: invalid_array_arg] undefined` If I just use the token like that. I think they need client_id and client_secret in the token

Comment: According to the source code, it takes a string: https://github.com/slackhq/node-slack-client/blob/master/lib/clients/rtm/client.js#L32 / https://github.com/slackhq/node-slack-client/blob/master/lib/clients/client.js#L20

Comment: yeah you are right but the formatting of that string is nowhere to be seen other than a clue here > https://www.npmjs.com/package/slack#test-setup-

Comment: They're using an `.env` file to set the environment variables - so effectively, that file is setting `process.env.SLACK_TOKEN`, `process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_ID` and `process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET`. You don't to pass in all three if you're hard-coding it.